# gunicorn cant start flask project ec2 ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, flask, amazon-ec2, python-3.6, gunicorn

I've just deployed in a Ubuntu EC2 machine, a Flask Python 3 application. I've successfully deployed on port 6001 just using `python3 src/server.py`. I have my app running but when I use the `gunicorn -w 4 -b 0.0.0.0:6001 server:app` line after stopping the Flask server it quits with an error that seems like it can not do the imports as shown in the image.

Tried this on my Ubuntu machine from my own AWS and this works perfectly although on my machine I don't have to install `gunicorn`.

Also tried using `uwsgi --http 0.0.0.0:6000 --module server:app` but it aborts with a `http is ambiguous error` message.

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from src.controller.token import getTokenLibery

app= Flask(__name__,template_folder='views')
#@app.route('/token')
@app.route('/handle_data', methods=['POST'])
def generateToken():
    try:
        email = request.form['email']
        tokenliberty=getTokenLibery(email)
        #print("valor correcto de response=")
        #print(tokenliberty)
        if str(tokenliberty).find("true") >= 0:   # value seems to be=  "b'true'"
            render= render_template('retrieveUser_Response.html')
            return render
        else:
            render= render_template('retrieveUserbadaResponse.html')
            return render
    except Exception:
        render= render_template('retrieveUserbadaResponse.html')
        return render

@app.route('/')
def getform():
   # render= render_template('retrieveUser_Response.html')
    render= render_template('retrieveUser.html')
    return render

if __name__== '__main__':
    #app.run(port=5000)
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=6001)
```

Using `python3 server.py`:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-81:~/passRecov/src$ python3 server.py
 * Serving Flask app "server" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:6001/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Using `gunicorn -w 4 -b 0.0.0.0:6001 server:app`:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-81:~/passRecov/srcgunicorn -w 4 -b 0.0.0.0:6001 server:app
[2019-10-03 15:18:13 +0000] [10731] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
[2019-10-03 15:18:13 +0000] [10731] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:6001 (10731)
[2019-10-03 15:18:13 +0000] [10731] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2019-10-03 15:18:13 +0000] [10735] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10735
[2019-10-03 15:18:13 +0000] [10735] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 578, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 135, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 377, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/home/ubuntu/passRecov/src/server.py", line 4, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, render_template, request
ImportError: No module named flask
[2019-10-03 15:18:13 +0000] [10735] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10735)
[2019-10-03 15:18:13 +0000] [10731] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2019-10-03 15:18:13 +0000] [10731] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-81:~/passRecov/src$
```

Answer (score 0):

When you launch gunicorn its running with the system installed python which is `2.7` as you can see in the stacktrace.  This doesn't have Flask installed, hence the error.

This is what virutal environments are for, which I don't think you're using at the moment.  `venvs` keep project dependencies isolated and avoid issues like this.

---

The way to run this properly is to make sure python3's venv module is installed:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-venv
```

Then for each new project, create a venv and activate it:

```
python3 -m venv venv
. venv/bin/activate
```

Your prompt should now change to:

```
(venv) ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-81:~/passRecov/src $
```

... which indicates you're in that virtual environment.  (Type `deactivate` and the prompt returns to normal).

Install stuff like this:

```
pip install gunicorn flask
```

Get a version frozen output of what's installed with:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt`
```

That `txt` file now contains the list, which you should commit to version control.  Any time you need to re-create an identical environment, create and activate it (as above) then do:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

---

Running `gunicorn` at this stage (provided your venv is active; the shell prompt starts with `(venv)`) it should work.

Comment: No probs.  You should click to accept the answer in which case :)